# How can I work with typed arrays without using for?

Tags: javascript, html, buffer, arrays

```
var sendBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(4096);
var dv = new DataView(sendBuffer);
dv.setInt32(0, 1234);
var service = svcName;
for (var i = 0; i < service.length; i++) 
{
    dv.setUint8(i + 4, service.charCodeAt(i));
}
ws.send(sendBuffer);
```

how to workout this wihout using for loop. for loop decreasing performance while  works with huge amount of data.

Comment: The for loop itself isn't what's slow - but what you're doing in the for loop. A different type of loop to go over the data isn't going to be faster.

Comment: Cache the `length` that will make it considerably faster. `for(var i=0, l=services.length; i<l; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, for() loops are very tight and efficient relative to other operations. Doing this sequentially on every permutation (i.e. getting rid of the for() loop) would be inelegant and also not save you very many cycles.

If an operation is likely to cause a client to grind to a halt, you need to split the problem into smaller components and give a warning to the user that performing the operation will take some time.

I would recommend splitting this operation into smaller chunks instead of trying to find another algorithm that doesn't use for().

Perhaps like this, using callbacks prevent the code from blocking:

```
var split = service.length/4;
function alpha(split, position, callback) {
  for (var i = split*(position-1); i < split*(position); i++) {
    dv.setUint8(i + 4, service.charCodeAt(i));}
  if(callback && (typeof(callback) == 'function') {
    callback();}
}

var split = service.length/4;
alpha(split, 1, function() {
  // poll here for other information or to confirm user wishes to proceed
  alpha(split, 2, function() {
    // poll here for other information or to confirm user wishes to proceed
    alpha(split, 3, function() {
      // poll here for other information or to confirm user wishes to proceed
      alpha(split, 4);}
  }
}
```

This is an *enormously* simplified and not the best way to implement this solution. But it will give you a chance to optimize the processing going on and prioritize the operations in relation to other ops.

Comment: service data is huge so it makes ui block when using this aproach and the browser  is going to hault.

Comment: Perfect, then just split it up like I have shown you. This will prevent the browser from halting with the dreaded "this page has stopped responding" message. :)

Comment: Splitting up the processing like in this answer would not prevent the page stopping responding.

Comment: There, I added callbacks to the code which will prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

As based on the comments your real problem is that the loop will make your UI to block.

The split answer above does not give you a proper way to prevent blocking. Everything done in the Javascript main thread will block the UI.

You need to use Web Workers (separate threads) for processing your data, so the processing does not block the UI thread:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/09/Workers-ArrayBuffer

You post the data to the separate worker for processing using postMessage() and then post the resulting data back to the main thread using another postMessage().